# Ubuntu Virtual machine on Win7 has network access but is not able to upgrade or wget

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm having a bizarre (to me) problem probably related to the way my company's network is set up.

I set up my virtual machine the way they suggest here

https://askubuntu.com/a/424368

And I am able to ping to the company site, but not to google.com or 8.8.8.8. This is the same behaviour that I see when use cmd from Windows.

[image: Strange network behaviour]
What's odd is that even on port 80 traffic, I am not able to communicate with the outside world. I have tried `wget`ing google.com, and using `apt-get update`, but both of these do not connect. Neither of these work when my VM is set up to use NAT either.

Any idea how I can set up my machine to receive updates and packages? I'm open to downloading the packages, but so far, some of the utilities I've seen have gone out of development and other solutions such as mirroring the 2TB repository are out of the question.

Edit: There are other solutions, such as taking the vm file home with me, or using ssh to connect to a home server via port 80, if that's even going to work, which I'm not convinced it will. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your company is blocking all the traffic and that only browsing is allowed through a proxy.

1. check the proxy settings on windows
2. if there's a proxy configured configure your VM to use it

Comment: I did look in to proxy settings, but understood that if I set up my computer in that fashion, it would use the proxy settings from my host machine. I guess I'm not really sure what my host and port would be, following these directions- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1575

Comment: Also, going into my internet settings, it says I am not configured for a proxy, managed or otherwise.

Comment: Try, from windows command prompt: telnet www.google.com 80

Comment: If it hangs on "Trying w.x.y.z..." port 80 is inaccessible from your network and browsing works probably using a proxy (maybe autoconfigured)

Comment: It does hang. A colleague of mine mentioned the proxy yesterday and I found the proxy server on a document; I spent an hour or so trying to put http_proxy in different files, but no internet access so far.

Comment: Now I'm really lost. I followed this http://askubuntu.com/questions/489852/proxy-authentication-with-terminal-ubuntu-14-04 and when I logged in as root, `sudo apt-get update` worked.

Comment: Ok. Now open Internet explorer and check: Internet Properties->Connections -> LAN Settings and see what you find there (is use a proxy server flagged? is automatically detect fallged?) - Post also the results of command: netsh winhttp show proxy (given on the windows command line)

Comment: Automatically detect is flagged. That command returns "Current WinHTTP proxy settings: Direct access (no proxy server)."

Comment: 1) try opening the url: http://wpad - 2) give us some details about the proxy mentioned by your colleague

Comment: He just said there was a proxy and didn't know the address. He also said he knew how to set this up through the GUI but not the terminal.

Comment: Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol is how Wep Proxy Auto Configuration works. If the proxy is autoconfigured you should find out how your pc gets the wpad.pac settings

Comment: I looked up the instructions for Filezilla as an example on the company helpdesk, they just say to put in the proxy address http://example.com and the port. Nothing about logging in or anything. I tried the link I posted earlier, and instead of hanging now, it's saying "Connection failed"

Comment: So you have instructions giving you a proxy address and a port? Correct?

Comment: Yes. I have a proxy address which I believe is correct and a port which I believe is also correct, but I am following the directions that I posted, and I still cannot connect out. I looked at the wikipedia link, but I'm not seeing any actionables.

Comment: Let's check the proxy: in the cmdline do a "telnet proxy.ip.address port" and see what happens

Comment: As in, `telnet example.com port#`? I tried that, and it said it could not open a connection to the host.

Comment: Yes, supposing your proxy ip is 1.2.3.4 and proxy port 3128, with `telnet 1.2.3.4 3128` you can check if something is listening on that ip address/port. If you got no reply I suppose the informations you've got about the proxy are not correct.

Comment: I got it sorted. The answer was that I did not need to log into the proxy. For some reason, providing my domain login details was creating unexpected behavior and for it to fail. I tried it without my login details bypassing `ntlmaps,' and it worked, and on reinstalling the virtual machine I put the proxy details in during installation and everything worked out of the box. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I'm happy that in the end you got it working! And now good browsing and updating ;-)